# UIView frame not in the same place as referenced frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uivisualeffectview

```
var visualEffectview = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView
visualEffectview.frame = self.filterPanel.frame
self.mapView.addSubview(visualEffectview)
```

I am trying to place a blur effect over a portion of a map. The code above makes this work, however the Y coordinate of the effect is slightly offset. Is this because some form of conversion needs to take place?

I can't figure out why the effect view isn't in exactly the same place as the `filterPanel` as the code would suggest. Any ideas?

Arrow shows where the blur starts (you can see it's offset below by a few pixels, should start at the top of the view containing the segmented control):

[image]

Comment: you say "should start at the top of the view containing the segmented control" but based on that image it looks like your segmented control view is also offset, it's overlaying onto the map area above.

Answer (score 0):

Is the 0,0 coordinate of self.filterPanel and self.mapView the same point?

If 0,0 is not the same pixel on the screen in both views, then when you add the effect as a sub view it would appear offset as you set the frame before you add it.

I think you correct this by doing something like

```
visualEffectView.frame=
  [self.filterPanel convertRect:self.filterPanel.frame toView:self.mapView];
then add it as a subview.
```

Comment: I tried your code but sadly it didn't work (just removed the blur), I updated the question with an image

Comment: From the picture I would say it is definitely coordinate conversion related and looking at the size on the picture I would say it relates to the status bar offset. Perhaps you have the map constrained to the top layout guide. If so you need to subtract the height of the status bar which is what the coordinate conversion should do. A simple test is to subtract the 20pt status bar height. Or constrain the map to the actual top.

Comment: I think you're definitely along the right lines with it being to do with constraints but sadly it's not to do with the status bar (tested as you suggested). Any more ideas?

Comment: Did you try visualEffectview.frame.origin.y-=20.0; If that lines up the blur then you know it is definitely status bar related and a y offset issue. What is the top constraint for the map? Also what is self.filterPanel and where is it in the view hierarchy.

Comment: I tried the origin -= 20, -= 16 is perfect but 20 is too much so I think that rules out status bar. The top constraint is Map View.Top = Top Layout Guide.Bottom. Here is the view hierachy: http://i.imgur.com/70G1uTw.png

Comment: Ok, next option is that when you did the constraints you had the "constrain to margins" on some of them. I had that problem when some had been set with margin and some not. For views the margin seems to be 8 at each edge for a view in a view. Have a look at the constraints on the map view. Perhaps its top and bottom is set with margins. If so set without constrain to margin on. Could be on any of your constraints. Sounds likely given 2x8=16?

Comment: Got it! It was in viewDidLoad, moved to viewDidAppear and now it works fine! Thanks so much for your advice anyway.